# Smoothing factor of Exponential Moving Average

Tags: volatility

I'm trying to implement an Exponential Moving Average indicator, but I'm sort of stuck on the smoothing factor. What I've come up with:

$$\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{k=0}^N \alpha^{k} P_k$$
Where **N** is the window of days in consideration, **k** loops through the days, **$ \alpha $** is a smoothing factor and **P** is the price.

What should I use for a smoothing factor? Is there any general guidelines? And am I even near the final product?

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{1}{\sum_{k=0}^N \alpha^{k} }\sum_{k=0}^N \alpha^{k} P_k$?

Comment: A key property of a moving average is that if all observations are equal to P (a constant) the moving average should also be equal to P. See Gordon's remark.

Answer (score 1):

The smoothing factor is a way to specify the **memory** of your estimator. This view provides a simple and natural way to tune $a$. Say you want the $k$th term in the past to weight for 1% in your estimation. It gives you
$$\frac{\alpha^k}{ A} = \frac{1}{100},$$ with $A$ your normalizing factor (see @Gordon's remark).

Of course you can do better than that. For instance if you assume a model on $P(t)$ dynamics, plug it into the moving average and try to control the variance of the sliding estimator.

Answer (score 0):

In the proprietary/branded Risk Metrics implementation of EWMA, I believe a smoothing factor of .97 is used. Here is a paper that discusses different smoothing factors for EWMA

http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00036846.2014.982853?journalCode=raec20